Is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ the "best" we can do to create a sequence of polynomials that share both coefficients and roots?
Let $P_1, P_2, P_3, \dots \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a sequence of polynomials (where the degree of $P_n$ is denoted by $d_n$, and the set of its roots over $\mathbb{C}$ is denoted by $R_n$) such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$P_n$ divides $P_{n+1}$ and $d_{n+1} > d_n$
$x^{d_n+1}$ divides $P_{n+1} - P_n$

This basically means that each of the $P_n$ can be thought of as a finite prefix of the same infinite series $\hat{P} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i $, with two nice properties - they (a) "share coefficients" (by being prefixes of the same infinite series) and (b) they "share roots" (since $P_n$ dividing $P_{n+1}$ implies $R_n \subseteq R_{n+1}$).
I am interested in how slowly $d_n$ can grow as a function of $n$.
At first I thought I could make $d_n$ equal $n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but it quickly breaks down because the moment you fix a linear $P_1$, and a quadratic $P_2$, no cubic $P_3$ will do.
As I played with small examples, I found myself struggling to beat the polynomials emerging from the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i$. This results in $P_1 = 1$, $P_2 = 1 + x$, $P_3 = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3$, and in general, $P_n$ will have degree $d_n = 2^{n-1} - 1$ and $R_n$ will contain the primitive $k^\text{th}$ roots of unity for $k \in \{2, 4, 8, \dots, 2^{n-1}\}$, so we have $R_n \subseteq R_{n+1}$ (with $R_1 = \phi$).
So my question is, can we can beat $d_n = 2^{n-1} - 1$ (i.e. have a lower bound)? And if so, what's the best we can do?

I think it has something to do with how many degrees of freedom you get by adding higher order terms to an already existing polynomial such that you preserve all the roots, but I could not get a handle on how to quantify that.
That is, suppose we have $P = \sum_{i=0}^{d} a_i x^i$ and $Q = \sum_{i=0}^{d} a_i x^i + \sum_{j=0}^{e-d-1} b_j x^{d+j+1} $, where the $a_i$ ($0 \leq i \leq d)$ are fixed and the $b_j$ ($0 \leq j \leq e-d-1$) are "free variables" with $b_{e-d-1} \neq 0$ and $e > d$. If $P$ divides $Q$, we know all the roots of $P$ satisfy $Q$ and so we inherit roughly $d$ constraints (depending on how many roots are repeated) on the $b_j$. But, I can't seem to get a bound for how big $e$ must get in order to ensure that some $b_j$s will even work out. If we can even say that $e$ must roughly equal $2d$, at least we might be able to get that $d_n = 2^{n - 1}$ is asymptotically tight. But without knowing what the $a_j$s are, I don't even know how to start answering this question - any pointers will be much appreciated!
This also explains my interest in the question - there are degrees of freedom you get by adding extra roots to a polynomial and there are degrees of freedom you get by adding extra higher order terms, and I would like to understand how they relate to each other.

Edit: Originally, my question claimed that considering truncations of $\frac{x}{1-x}$ was the best you could do because I was implicitly assuming all my polynomials had roots, but dropping that assumption (so we can divide by $x$) results in a neater series and a better bound, so edited my question. Thanks @anankElpis for the suggestion in the comments.

Write the divisibility conditions as $$P_{n+1}=fP_n\qquad\text{and}\qquad P_{n+1}-P_n=gx^{d_n+1}$$ for some nonzero $f,g\in\mathbb Z[x]$ with $\deg(f)>0$. Substituting $P_{n+1}$, this yields \begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}gx^{d_n+1}=(f-1)P_n\end{equation}
Note that the left side is divisible by a large power of $x$, while $P_n$ contains the terms of $P_1$, so can't be divisible by too large a power of $x$. Therefore, the degree of $f$ can't be too small. We make this observation precise in the following way:

For $h\in\mathbb Z[x]$, denote by $\nu(h)$ the degree of the smallest nonzero monomial of $h$, i.e. $$\nu\left(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\right)=\min\{i\mid a_i\neq0\}.$$ (In other words, $\nu$ is the valuation associated to the prime ideal $(x)$.) Note that $\nu(fg)=\nu(f)+\nu(g)$ and $\nu(f)\leq\deg(f)$ for $f,g\neq0$. Now apply $\nu$ to equation $(\ast)$: We have \begin{align}d_n+1&\leq d_n+1+\nu(g)=\nu(gx^{d_n+1})=\nu((f-1)P_n)=\nu(f-1)+\nu(P_n)\\&=\nu(f-1)+\nu(P_1)\leq\deg(f)+d_1\end{align} This implies \begin{align}\tag{$\ast\ast$}d_{n+1}=\deg(P_{n+1})=\deg(fP_n)=\deg(f)+d_n\geq2d_n+1-d_1.\end{align} An easy induction finally shows that $$\boxed{d_{n+1}\geq 2^n+d_1-1\geq2^n-1.}$$

The minimum $d_{n+1}=2^n-1$ is obtained by $P_n=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}x^i$, and this is essentially the only solution: We need equality for all inequalities above, in particular $\deg(P_1)=0$ and $\nu(f-1)=\deg(f)=2^{n-1}$, i.e. $f=1+ax^{2^{n-1}}$. For $a=1$ this yields the $P_n$ above, other values result in different multiples, of the form $$P_n=a_1+a_2x+a_3(x^2+x^3)+a_4(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)+\ldots$$ with $a_i\mid a_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

Thanks! Your valuation of considering the highest power of $x$ that divides the polynomial is neat and does the trick splendidly
